# My "install module" link

Tags: 7

"install module" link disappears from module section in "Drupal 7" for some reason.How can this link enable to install my new modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `admin/modules` and
Enable **Update Manager** under **CORE** modules list

[image]

> **Update Manager:** Checks for available updates, and can securely install or update modules and themes via a web interface.

Comment: Wow, That is really the direct solution to my issue.Thanks

Comment: $reputation<15..:(

Comment: @DrupalDeveloper Sorry I don't understand your comment. Even though you have less reputation you can approve the answer :)